# Level/Asset design for performance Unity

Tags: unity, textures, performance, levels

I am a big fan of modular assets.
Currently I am designing a 3d game for mobile and I don't know how I should create my levels to get the most out of the device.

Should I...

create lots of "small" (1x1x1 meter) assets and build my level using them
or create one geometry for the entire level?

What about textures?
Should "all" objects share one highres texture and only display their part using the right UV settings (like say in minecraft)
or should I create an individual texture for each object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots way of optimization including

1. [LOD](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LevelOfDetail.html) - hig and low poly object display according to camera
2. [Culling](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OcclusionCulling.html) - show only camera frustam obects
3. [mesh combine](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.CombineMeshes.html) - [combine meshes](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/8748)
4. [World streamer](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/36486) (dividing scene into sub-scene then load/unload according to camera position)

Maybe what you are talking about is the fourth option divide your scene into multiple scene using this package and enjoy good performance.

*Remember: before purchasing any package you need to carryout some research according to your requirements*

Comment: I am torn between mesh combine and culling. My game would have hundrets of static objects with a similar geometry, but different textures. Think of a static minecraft level. :)

Comment: then use mesh combine and texture combine

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25545506/combine-array-of-sprite-objects-into-one-sprite-unity